How to make an algorithm box smaller inside a figure environment?
I have following code for an algorithm block:
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}

\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}

%
\makeatletter
\def\algbackskip{\hskip\dimexpr-\algorithmicindent+\labelsep}
\def\LState{\Statex \algbackskip}%
\makeatother
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
%
%\algblock{Input}{EndInput}
%\algnotext{EndInput}
%\algblock{Output}{EndOutput}
%\algnotext{EndOutput}
%
%
\begin{figure}[!t]
\removelatexerror
\centering
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{: Parasitic-Aware Signal Routing (PASR)}
  \begin{algorithmic}[]
    \setstretch{1.1}
    \LState \textbf{Input}: $\rho$\textsubscript{i,n} of input list \textit{i\textsubscript{n}} $\in$ \{\textit{PP\textsubscript{ij}}, \textit{$\tau$\textsubscript{i0}}, \textit{$\tau$\textsubscript{i1}}, \textit{c\textsubscript{i}}, \textit{$\overline{S}$\textsubscript{i}}, $\alpha$\textsubscript{i}, \textit{S\textsubscript{ij}}, \textit{Co\textsubscript{i}}\}; \textit{n} $\in \mathbb{N}$; 0$\leq$\textit{n}$<$3        
    \LState \textbf{Output}: Optimum \textit{i\textsubscript{n}} assignment to \textit{FA\textsubscript{i}} inputs
    \vspace{2mm}
    \LState  Connect \textit{i\textsubscript{n}} of max\textit{\{$\rho$\textsubscript{i,n} : n=0,...,2\}} to pin \textbf{\textit{C}}
    \LState Update the list \textit{i\textsubscript{n}}; 0$\leq$\textit{n}$<$2
    \If{$\rho$\textsubscript{i,0} $\not\approx$ $\rho$\textsubscript{i,1}}
       \State Connect \textit{i\textsubscript{n}} of max\textit{\{$\rho$\textsubscript{i,n} : n=0,1\}} to pin \textbf{\textit{A}}
       \State Connect last \textit{i\textsubscript{n}} to pin \textbf{\textit{B}}
    \Else
       \State Connect \textit{i\textsubscript{n}} of max\textit{\{$\gamma$\textsubscript{i,n\_0} : n=0,1\}} to pin \textbf{\textit{B}}
       \State Connect last \textit{i\textsubscript{n}} to pin \textbf{\textit{A}}
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
  \vspace{-3mm}
\caption{A greedy algorithm for signal flow optimization in adder-tree}
\label{fig:GR_ALG}
\end{figure}
%
% 

This creates the block inside a figure environment. How can we make the entire environment smaller in size ? Can we do it without changing the algorithm block text ?


Welcome! Please make your code compilable.

Hi, I added the missing \usepackage s from the preamble. Above code is compilable with that.
